# Flatten triple-nested JSON with normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-2.7

I am trying to flatten the following but it only works for a non triple-nested JSON.

Working code:

import json

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = [{'masterName': 'AAAAAAAAAAA',
         'shortname': 'AA',
         'info': {
              'name': 'randomka'
         },
         'mainNames': [{'date': '2019-05-16', 'NumberOne': 1111},
                       {'date': '2019-06-22', 'NumberOne': 2222}]}
       ]

result = json_normalize(data, 'mainNames', ['masterName', 'shortname',
                                          ['info', 'name']],errors='ignore')
```

Not working:

```
data2 = [{"masterName": "AAAAAAAAAAA",
          "mainNames": [
            {
                "numbers": [{
                        "date": "2019-05-16",
                        "NumberOne": 222}],
                "name": "randomka"
            },
            {
                "numbers": [{
                        "date": "2019-05-16",
                        "NumberOne": 222}],
                "name": "randomka"
            }
        ]
    }]

    json_normalize(data2, 'mainNames', ['masterName'],errors='ignore')
```

as it returns:

[image]

I have tried alternative `record_paths` and `metas` in the `json_normalize` code but I can't make it work for this triple-nested JSON. In other words, I can't take all the columns at one go.

Alternatives I have tried that worked and look close:

```
json_normalize(data2, ['mainNames','numbers'], ['masterName'],errors='ignore')
```

The output is pretty much an Excel view with data in columns. Expected view as per the comment requests:

[image]

UPD: Data might have more than one branch of numbers:

```
data2 = [{"masterName": "AAAAAAAAAAA",
          "mainNames": [
            {
                "numbers": [{
                        "date": "2019-05-16",
                        "NumberOne": 222}],
                "name": "randomka"
            },
            {
                "numbers": [{
                        "date": "2019-05-16",
                        "NumberOne": 222},
{
                        "date": "2019-07-01",
                        "NumberOne": 341}],
                "name": "randomka"
            }
        ]
    }]
```

Comment: Can you share the expected output? I am not familiar with this process normalizing. I'm sure sharing the expected output would help others as well. Anyway, is it acceptable to make your own function for this problem? I feel like that might take lesser time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Aayush Mahajan in the comments, it might be simpler to define your own function. Here is one working with `data2`:

```
out = []
data2 = data2[0]                                    # Remove first level
for main in data2["mainNames"]:                     # Iterate "mainNames"
    sub_dict = {"masterName": data2['mainNames']}   # Init new dict (df row) with "mainNames"
    sub_dict.update(main["numbers"][0])             # Add all fields from "numbers"
    sub_dict["name"] = main["name"]                 # Add "name" field

    out.append(sub_dict)                            # append sud dict to list outputs

print(out)
# [{'masterName': 'AAAAAAAAAAA', 'date': '2019-05-16', 'NumberOne': 222, 'name': 'randomka'},
#  {'masterName': 'AAAAAAAAAAA', 'date': '2019-05-16', 'NumberOne': 222, 'name': 'randomka'}]

# create Dataframe with from_dict
df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(out)
print(df)
#     masterName        date  NumberOne      name
# 0  AAAAAAAAAAA  2019-05-16        222  randomka
# 1  AAAAAAAAAAA  2019-05-16        222  randomka
```

**Update**:
You can add an inner `loop` to iterate over the `numbers` field:

```
out = []
data2 = data2[0]                                    # Remove first level
for main in data2["mainNames"]:                     # Iterate "mainNames"
    for numbers in main["numbers"]:
        sub_dict = {"masterName": data2['masterName']}  # Init new dict (df row) with "mainNames"
        sub_dict.update(numbers)                        # Add all fields from "numbers"
        sub_dict["name"] = main["name"]                 # Add "name" field

        out.append(sub_dict)                            # append sud dict to list outputs

print(out)
# [{'masterName': 'AAAAAAAAAAA', 'date': '2019-05-16', 'NumberOne': 222, 'name': 'randomka'},
#  {'masterName': 'AAAAAAAAAAA', 'date': '2019-05-16', 'NumberOne': 222, 'name': 'randomka'},
#  {'masterName': 'AAAAAAAAAAA', 'date': '2019-07-01', 'NumberOne': 341, 'name': 'randomka'}]

df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(out)
print(df)
#    NumberOne        date   masterName      name
# 0        222  2019-05-16  AAAAAAAAAAA  randomka
# 1        222  2019-05-16  AAAAAAAAAAA  randomka
# 2        341  2019-07-01  AAAAAAAAAAA  randomka
```

As well, it's still working with the initial `data2`.

Hope that helps !

Comment: That doesn't work when there are more than one number arrays.

Comment: @Apolo Radomer I answer according the sample you provided. If your data is actually different, share the worst case or add details.

Comment: I tried changing a lot with a for loop and didn't work for me. I have updated the question with the updated JSON.

Comment: I was so close. I had the ```sub_dict = {"masterName": data2['masterName']}``` outside the loop.